# What word is used when I have to say "I ________ the page in two parts"?

Tags: meaning

Two words I know are: "split" and "tear". But I want to know the correct word for the following sentences.

Which one should I use in, for example:

> I _______ a page from my notebook.

or

> I ________ the envelope to get the letter from it.

Comment: You tore the page from your notebook, and you opened the envelope, or tore it apart. Using "split" in either case is about as appropriate as using "fertilize".

Comment: 'split' is a lot more appropriate than 'fertilize'. You could split an envelope even though we normally 'open' one. Either way you can get the letter out. To fertilize an envelope makes no sense.

Comment: @ЯegDwight: I never *split* (or *fertilize*) my mail, but I have been known to ***slit*** envelopes with a [letter-opener](http://www.123rf.com/stock-photo/letter_opener.html)

Comment: You *tear* the paper and not *split* it unless it's Microsoft Word! :)

Comment: Vikar - Your question is very confusing. Your title poses one question and then you go on to ask a different one. Could you edit to make it clear what you wish us to answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'Exact' word? Such a thing rarely exists. Most people will use "tear", but someone could use "part" or "divide" or "cut" or "chop" or "rend" depending on the situation, their dialect, deeper sense of the action, or even their mood.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a deliberate and considered act I would ***remove*** a page from a notebook. If I did it in a fit of rage I would probably ***tear*** it from the book.

I usually ***open*** envelopes - unless they are ones where I am desperate to see the contents and then I may ***tear*** or ***rip*** them open.